# Crontab its overwriting kitchen.sh pentaho's jobs

Tags: linux, cron, pentaho, jobs

Java consumes high amounts of RAM/memory and this kills the crontab task. I make a log file but it always overwrites it. I thought to make a script file to verify if it exists or not. But the log file always exists.

I have to make a script to verify if the Crontab Task is running, but I have no idea how to make this. I saw in another topic about lockfile, but I did not understand what lockfile is.

Comment: Can you please rephrase this? I honestly can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, im not so good in english. 
I'm trying to make a script file to handle crontab linux tasks, because my tasks are overwriting themselves.